# Setting to get SBT to fail fast (stop) on an error

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running a multi-project SBT (v0.13) build and would like it to *fail fast (stop)* on the first error (compile) encountered in a sub-project.

The current behavior is that when something fails to compile in a sub-project, the build continues (to compile all the other sub-projects).

Is there a way/setting to make SBT stop and exit as soon as the first sub-project with a compile error is encountered?

Answer (score 7):

In short, to my knowledge, no, SBT can not "fail fast" on a compiler or test error.

To my knowledge SBT doesn't control this. SBT is just going to invoke the appropriate test framework when it inspects your unit tests. The test framework can then decide what order to run the tests in, to run them concurrently, how to report issues, etc. Of course each test framework has its own features, configuration, and conventions. The two most widely used test frameworks for Scala are ScalaTest and Specs2.

Fortunately you can get the behavior you've requested in either Specs2 or ScalaTest. I've provided simple unit test examples below that fail early.

## ScalaTest

You can get fail-fast behavior in ScalaTest for single test Suites by mixing in the [CancelAfterFailure](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.CancelAfterFailure) trait. For example, this test would execute the first test, fail the second, and show the third as cancelled.

```
class SomeSuite extends FunSuite with CancelAfterFailure with Assertions {

  test("first") {
    println("first")
  }

  test("second") {
    assert(false)
  }

  test("third") {
    println("third")
  }
}
```

## Specs2

Similar to ScalaTest you can control behavior in Specs2 on a per-Specification basis. To get fail-fast-like behavior you need to add two Arguments to your Specification: `sequential` and `stopOnFail`. See [the docs](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.ArgumentsReference.html) for a full list of arguments you can set. (You do need both if you want an obvious linear ordering since Specs2 by default will execute your tests concurrently!)

```
class SomeSpec extends Specification {

  sequential
  stopOnFail

  "specs2" should {
    "first" in {
      println("first")
      ok
    }

    "second" in {
      "foo" must equalTo ("bar")
    }

    "third" in {
      println("third")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP was asking about failing fast at compile time, not at test time.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that throwing a `new java.lang.VirtualMachineError() {}` halts the task immediately, while all other kinds of exceptions I have tried so far were swallowed.

I've tried `ThreadDeath`, `InterruptedException`, `LinkageError`, and `ControlThrowable`, and of course, the usual `RuntimeException` and such (the list came from `scala.util.control.NonFatal`)

`<project root>/project/BuildUtils.scala`

```scala
import sbt._
import sbt.Def._

object BuildUtils {

  private def details(inc: Incomplete): Seq[Throwable] =
    inc.directCause.toSeq ++ inc.causes.flatMap(details)

  implicit class TaskSyntax[A](private val task: Initialize[Task[A]]) extends AnyVal {
    def haltWhenFailed: Initialize[Task[A]] = task.result.map {
      case Inc(cause) =>
        throw new VirtualMachineError({
          s"""Task has failed during execution.
             |TaskNode: ${cause.node}
             |DirectCause: ${details(cause).map(_.getMessage).distinct}
             |""".stripMargin
        }) {}
      case Value(value) => value
    }
  }

}
```

`<project root>/build.sbt`

```
import BuildUtils._

lazy val ciBuild = taskKey[Unit]("Compile and run test")

ciBuild := {
  val t1 @ _ = (Test / compile).haltWhenFailed.value
  val t2 @ _ = (Test / test).haltWhenFailed.value
}
```

`ciBuild` will halt at first compilation error with rather verbose stacktrace and the specified message.

Comment: Cool hack but sadly is not working with multiprojects ... I've tried to add ThisBuild and gives no error but also no tasks running ... I wonder what is missing